# How can I discover that an Avro schema structure is changed in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am using Kafka with Confluent components, included the schema registry. Some data are written down to a specific topic and the Avro schema structure can potentially change. How can I discover when a new structure is published to the registry and eventually publish an event for it to a separate topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> eventually publish an event for it to a separate topic?

Schemas are already all published into `_schemas` topic, by default. This is the Schema Registry backing store.

Comment: Is there any difference with using the schema registry client rest API?

Comment: Yes, the difference is that you'd have to write an HTTP poll loop against all subjects, all versions, etc rather than consuming the topic directly and getting the very latest schema events. In other words, the REST API doesn't "notify" clients of any changes